# Shopify: Change the availability of variants

Tags: jquery, filter, shopify

In my case Shopify product has 5 variants: `Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday`.

I want to limit variants within 48 hours. For example:

For Monday - `Wednesday, Thursday, Friday`

For Wednesday - `Monday, Tuesday, Friday`

For Friday - `Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday`

I'm wondering if I can use standard functions. Through the admin panel or internal structure of Shopify.

Comment: yes, you can do that using javascript

Comment: The complexity of the answer changes on whether you care about people who add products to their cart on Monday but don't check out until Friday, too...

Comment: @DaveB session for cart will be clean every new day

Comment: You could code up a rule through the Shopify's Liquid code right in the template then... Let's see...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter out variants that you don't want to display using Liquid, preventing shoppers from being able to add those products to the cart.

In your product template, find the line `{% for variant in product.variants %}`

Before this line, add `{% assign day_of_week = 'now' | date: '%A' %}` to store the current day-of-week in a Liquid variable

After this line, add code to filter out the variants that you do not want to see (below).  For each day of the week that you care about, you will need a 'when' statement followed by a check against some property of the variant (I used the variant title).  If it's a variant that you do not want to show, use the 'continue' statement to skip that variant and go on to the next.

Example:

```
{% assign day_of_week = 'now' | date: "%A" %}

{% for variant in product.variants %}
<!-- Addition below to filter out products that customer shouldn't see -->
  {% case day_of_week %}
    {% when 'Monday' %}
      {% if variant.title contains 'Monday' or variant.title contains 'Tuesday' %}{% continue %}{% endif %}
    {% when 'Tuesday' %}
      {% if variant.title contains 'Tuesday' or variant.title contains 'Wednesday' %}{% continue %}{% endif %}

<!-- Repeat for each day of the week -->
   {% endcase %}
  <!-- Regular code from your variant loop -->
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's what I need

Answer (score 0):

Separate from my other answer, you can also filter out variants using Javascript.  I generally prefer pre-filtering variants through Liquid - relying on Javascript may result in a flicker on page load as the variants are there briefly before the code runs.

Assuming that jQuery is already on the page, we could write this as:

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var variants_list = {{ product.variants | json }};
    var date = new Date(Date.now()).toDateString();

    for(var i=0; i < variants_list.length; i++){
      var variant = variants_list[i];
      if(variant.title == 'Monday' && (date.indexOf('Mon') > -1 || date.indexOf('Tue') > -1){
        jQuery('[value="' + variant.id + '"]').remove();
      //Note: If you theme uses swatches or anything like that, you may need to remove additional elements from the document as well.
      }
      if(variant.title == 'Tuesday' && (date.indexOf('Tue') > -1 || date.indexOf('Wed') > -1){
        jQuery('[value="' + variant.id + '"]').remove();
      }
    }
    //Lather-rinse-repeat for each day of the week that you care about

}
</script>
```